# Add-ADPermissions invalid cmdlet exception - SHOULD be there... Any thoughts?

Tags: powershell, plugins, permissions, active-directory, exchange-server

So I'm trying to link some mailboxes, and I'm running into some beef.

Running the following command:

Add-ADPermissions -identity ........................

I get the error 'Add-ADPermissions' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check blah blah blah.

I've done a little fishing around, and I found an answer that seemed to be about right - be sure you have the snapins enabled; but here's the beef:

After adding 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Support' and 'Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin' ( the latter was already installed ), I still can't execute the command.

First question:
Does anyone know where I can find a full list of AD PS Snapins for Exchange 2007?

Second Question:
Does anyone know which of those ( other than the above mentioned ) should contain the aforementioned command?

I'm a little flustered - finding a list is proving troublesome, and my issue seems to be fairly unique...

Thanks.

Comment: For starters i think [Add-ADPermission](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124403%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) is only for 2010 and 2013. Do you have 2007?

Comment: Running 2007; I found a thread that Touches on this in a 2007 installation here / http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/260562-powershell-script-need-to-grant-full-access-to-a-bunch-of-users-piped-in / that seemed to have a valid suggestion at the last reply; but after following it I still didn't have any luck.